# How to make usage information always shown when mouse over custom symbol without pressing Ctrl+Shift+K?

Tags: front-end

On my computer, Mathematica do not shown usage information pop up window when mouse over for custom symbol, unless I hit Ctrl+Shift+K. However, the built-in symbol always shown information pop when mouse over.

You can see the difference in below screen recording

[image]

You can see after hitting Ctrl+Shift+K, I got mouse over pop up automatically for custom symbol. **But this only works for this particular kernel session and this particular symbol**. If I want to mouse over other new symbol with usage, I need to hit Ctrl+Shift+K for that symbol, very annoying. **How to make usage information always pop up when mouse over for any custom symbol with usage information without pressing Ctrl+Shift+K one by one?**

Comment: Personally, I think that even if this can be achieved, FrontEnd will become unusable due to the interface freezes every time the mouse cursor is over a user-defined `Symbol`. Actually, I often wish to disable the auto-popups even for system symbols, because even they freeze up the unterface for a while.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Hi, Thank you for comment. I have different feelings : )  First, I do not encounter any front end freeze with pop up, as you can see from my smooth gif : ), so that is not an issue for me. Second, during my working, I actually do not see pop up when I move my cursor, until I want to see the pop up, so I never felt any disturbance when I working. Anyway, different people have different needs, it should be customizable : )